# Optical Character Recognition Multiple Line Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ocr

I'm building an OCR. For that I'm using `CNN`, `RNN` and `CTC` Loss Function.
My input layer gets image and output layer predicts what's written on that image. Labels are converted into integer.

```
['A', 'B', 'C'] -> A = 0, B = 1, C = 2
```

If the image is ABC, training label will be 0,1,2 (Single row vector)

I'm able to accomplish this on single line. For eg. '`ABCDE`' is written on an image and model works great. But if the image is

```
'ABC'

'CAB'
```

then what should be the training label ? How can I tell the model about next line ? I want to train a model on multiple line.

Comment: You can preprocess the image to separate it into single lines. It could be much easier than detect the whole image with multiple lines.

Comment: @HaBom I thought of that idea. I tried opencv mser, contours but didn't work very well. If you have any idea how I can crop my images into separate lines, please share. Keep in mind that image might be tilted as well.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to **recognize text of a document containing multiple lines**. There are **two ways** to achieve this:

1. **Segment** the document into **lines** as a **pre-processing** step, then feed each segmented line separately into your neural network.
   If you want to go this way, e.g. read the paper [1] from Bunke and Marti. They essentially count the black-white transitions for each scanline and create a histogram out of it. They use the minimums of the histogram to split the document into individual lines. There are some other methods too to segment a document into lines.
2. **Train** the **neural network** to **implicitly segment** the document into **lines**.
   You need to add attention to the neural network, such that it can focus on individual lines.
   Bluche has done some great work towards text recognition on document-level. 
   See the paper [2] and the website [3].

[1] Bunke, Marti: The IAM-database: an English sentence database for offline handwriting recognition. Download via Springer

[2] Bluche: Joint Line Segmentation and Transcription for End-to-End Handwritten Paragraph Recognition. Download via https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08352

[3] Bluche: Scan, Attend and Read. See http://www.tbluche.com/scan_attend_read.html and look for "Handwriting Recognition with MDLSTM and CTC" and "The Collapse Layer and its Proposed Replacements"

Comment: Hi @Harry. Thank you for help. This is what I want but being a naive in deep learning, I didn't know how to implement Multi Dimensional LSTM and also didn't find any good tutorial. Would be very grateful if you point in right direction.

Comment: I don't know of any open-source implementation of "Scan, Attend and Read" - maybe ask T. Bluche if he open-sourced his code. I think that this full-page text-recognition approach is the way to go (and will get more adapted in the future), but I also think it's quite some work to develop such a system.
Open-source implementations of MD-LSTM are available, even in TensorFlow, e.g. look for tf.contrib.ndlstm.